# Por qué no muestra el mensaje al denegar acceso a la ubicación

Tags: javascript

Al darle click en denegar o bloquear ubicación no sale el mensaje que debería salir, por qué no lo muestra?

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message");

function getLocation() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
  
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    
  } else { 
  
    message.innerHTML = "No podemos acceder a tu ubicación.";
    
  }
  
}

function showPosition(position) {

  message.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  
}
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Ubicación</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inténtalo de esta forma

```
const getLocation =()=>new Promise((res,rej)=> 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(accept=>res(accept), deny=>rej(deny));
```

Y lo mandas a llamar `getLocation()`
Solo es cuestión de esperar a que se resuelva la promesa con su then

Comment: No, el problema está en el uso de message.

Comment: Con el debido respeto, pero su hate no tiene fundamento por dos motivos
1.- En ningun lado dije cuál era el error y 2 el código que puse es 100% funcional y libre de side effects

Comment: Tu respuesta no ayuda en absoluto a solucionar el problema, por eso le di un -1.

Comment: echale ganas carnal, si aprendiendo y tal vez algun dia llegues a ser un Sr. Associate Staff Engineer como tu servidor https://enetojara.github.io

Answer (score -1):

Estás declarando la variable message esperando que coja el elemento del DOM identificado por "message", pero ese elemento no existe en ese momento, porque ese Javascript se está ejecutando antes de pintar el elemento.

Si mueves el Javascript al final del body, te funcionará:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="message"></p>
<button onclick="getLocation();">Ubicación</button>
<script>
var message = document.getElementById("message");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    message.innerHTML = "No podemos acceder a tu ubicación."; 
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  message.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra opción es hacer que el Javascript se ejecute una vez cargada la página. Esto dejo que lo investigues por tu cuenta.

Comment: Esto lo explica todo xD

Comment: Acepta mi respuesta si te sirvió ;)